# Magic-the-Gathering Challenge: Cheapest Legacy Turn 1 kill

Tags: open-ended, magic-the-gathering

Your Goal: Win the game turn 1 with you beginning the game (so not on the draw) using the cheapest price total of cards used.

Rules:

- Use the "Price Trend" price from http://www.magiccardmarket.eu
- For each card used, provide a link to the magiccardmarket page of that card
- Basic lands are considered free
- [Legacy](http://magic.wizards.com/en/gameinfo/gameplay/formats/legacy) banlist applies
- Your opponent's deck consists entirely of basic Islands and keeps his hand of 7 cards
- You may stack your deck as you like, even after shuffling
- You should not rely on your opponent for winning the game. If the opponent is given a choice, any possible choice should win you the game (so no choosing 20 with [Choice of Damnations](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=88803) for example, and with Chain Lightning kind of cards you should be able to win the game whether he chooses to copy or not)
- Extra turns are not allowed because I don't consider that still turn 1
- Do not rely on random actions like coin flipping or choosing cards at random

Of course prices tend to change so the best answer could change over time but that's ok. I'll re-evaluate answers regularly and most cheap cards are somewhat constant. I'll start off with an answer of my own.

Comment: Because it matters - does my opponent interact if they *may*, but are not forced to?  (i.e. Chain Lightning type spells) and do they keep a hand of 7, or mulligan? (I.e. Windfall)  Also, is my deck stacked for cards like Grenzo, Dungeon Warden?

Comment: @Zerris let's just say that you can't rely on your opponent to win the game. No matter what your opponent chooses you should win the game either way. They keep the hand of 7 cards and your complete deck is stacked how you like entirely, so also from the bottom up

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because [open-ended puzzles are off-topic](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6617/the-end-of-open-ended-puzzles) as of May 2019 (also, a puzzle where the answers change over time is... not how this site works)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Total Price: €0,47**

Cards Used:

> 53x Swamp
>
>  2x *Any Bulk Green Common* - €0,00
>
>  [Dead Drop (Khans of Tarkir)](https://www.magiccardmarket.eu/Products/Singles/Khans+of+Tarkir/Dead+Drop) - €0,03
>
>  2x [Erratic Explosion (Onslaught)](https://www.magiccardmarket.eu/Products/Singles/Onslaught/Erratic+Explosion) - €0,06
>
>  [Burnt Offering (Ice Age)](https://www.magiccardmarket.eu/Products/Singles/Ice+Age/Burnt+Offering) - €0,04
>
>  [Allosaurus Rider (Prerelease Promos)](https://www.magiccardmarket.eu/Products/Singles/Prerelease+Promos/Allosaurus+Rider) - €0,34

Play Order:

> Exile the two bulk green commons to play [Allosaurus Rider](https://www.magiccardmarket.eu/Products/Singles/Prerelease+Promos/Allosaurus+Rider)
>
>  Play Swamp and tap for B to play [Burnt Offering](https://www.magiccardmarket.eu/Products/Singles/Ice+Age/Burnt+Offering) on Allosaurus Rider for RRRRRRR
>
>  Play [Erratic Explosion](https://www.magiccardmarket.eu/Products/Singles/Onslaught/Erratic+Explosion) for RRR targeting your opponent
>
>  Reveal [Dead Drop](https://www.magiccardmarket.eu/Products/Singles/Khans+of+Tarkir/Dead+Drop) (the only non-land in your deck) to Erratic Explosion, dealing 10 damage
>
>  Play [Erratic Explosion](https://www.magiccardmarket.eu/Products/Singles/Onslaught/Erratic+Explosion) for RRR targeting your opponent
>
>  Reveal [Dead Drop](https://www.magiccardmarket.eu/Products/Singles/Khans+of+Tarkir/Dead+Drop) (the only non-land in your deck) to Erratic Explosion, dealing 10 damage

*Winning through straight combat damage is a bit more expensive, but still under €1,00:*

**Total Price: €0,91**

Cards Used:

> Swamp
>
>  2x *Any Bulk Green Common* - €0,00
>
>  [Burnt Offering (Ice Age)](https://www.magiccardmarket.eu/Products/Singles/Ice+Age/Burnt+Offering) - €0,04
>
>  [Hammerhand (Magic 2015)](https://www.magiccardmarket.eu/Products/Singles/Magic+2015/Hammerhand) - €0,10
>
>  [Allosaurus Rider (Prerelease Promos)](https://www.magiccardmarket.eu/Products/Singles/Prerelease+Promos/Allosaurus+Rider) - €0,34
>
>  [Minion of the Wastes (Tempest)](https://www.magiccardmarket.eu/Products/Singles/Tempest/Minion+of+the+Wastes) - €0,43

Play Order:

> Exile the two bulk green commons to play [Allosaurus Rider](https://www.magiccardmarket.eu/Products/Singles/Prerelease+Promos/Allosaurus+Rider)
>
>  Play Swamp and tap for B to play [Burnt Offering](https://www.magiccardmarket.eu/Products/Singles/Ice+Age/Burnt+Offering) on Allosaurus Rider for BBBRRRR
>
>  Play [Minion of the Wastes](https://www.magiccardmarket.eu/Products/Singles/Tempest/Minion+of+the+Wastes) for BBBRRR, paying 19 life for a 19/19
>
>  Play [Hammerhand](https://www.magiccardmarket.eu/Products/Singles/Magic+2015/Hammerhand) for R enchanting Minion of the Wastes (giving it haste and +1/+1)
>
>  Move to combat and swing for 20 damage

---

*Previous Solutions*

---

Total Price: €0,58

Cards Used:

> Forest
>
>  [Myr Moonvessel (Darksteel)](https://www.magiccardmarket.eu/Products/Singles/Darksteel/Myr+Moonvessel) - €0,04
>
>  [Infernal Plunge (Innistrad)](https://www.magiccardmarket.eu/Products/Singles/Innistrad/Infernal+Plunge) - €0,09
>
>  [Tinder Wall (Ice Age)](https://www.magiccardmarket.eu/Products/Singles/Ice+Age/Tinder+Wall) - €0,18
>
>  [Blood Oath (Mercadian Masques)](https://www.magiccardmarket.eu/Products/Singles/Mercadian+Masques/Blood+Oath) - €0,27

Play Order:

> Play Forest, tap for G (G)
>
>  Play [Tinder Wall](https://www.magiccardmarket.eu/Products/Singles/Ice+Age/Tinder+Wall) for G, sacrifice it for RR (RR)
>
>  Play [Myr Moonvessel](https://www.magiccardmarket.eu/Products/Singles/Darksteel/Myr+Moonvessel) for R, play [Infernal Plunge](https://www.magiccardmarket.eu/Products/Singles/Innistrad/Infernal+Plunge) for R on Myr Moonvessel for 1RRR (1RRR)
>
>  Play [Blood Oath](https://www.magiccardmarket.eu/Products/Singles/Mercadian+Masques/Blood+Oath) for 1RRR, naming "Land" for 21 damage

Total Price: €0,77

Cards Used:

> 53x Mountain
>
>  [Erratic Explosion (Onslaught)](https://www.magiccardmarket.eu/Products/Singles/Onslaught/Erratic+Explosion) - €0,03
>
>  [Dead Drop (Khans of Tarkir)](https://www.magiccardmarket.eu/Products/Singles/Khans+of+Tarkir/Dead+Drop) - €0,03
>
>  [Myr Moonvessel (Darksteel)](https://www.magiccardmarket.eu/Products/Singles/Darksteel/Myr+Moonvessel) - €0,04
>
>  2x [Infernal Plunge (Innistrad)](https://www.magiccardmarket.eu/Products/Singles/Innistrad/Infernal+Plunge) - €0,18
>
>  [Ornithopter (Fourth Edition)](https://www.magiccardmarket.eu/Products/Singles/Fourth+Edition/Ornithopter) - €0,12
>
>  [Reverberate (Magic 2012)](https://www.magiccardmarket.eu/Products/Singles/Magic+2012/Reverberate) - €0,37

Play Order:

> Play Mountain, [Ornithopter](https://www.magiccardmarket.eu/Products/Singles/Fourth+Edition/Ornithopter)
>
>  Tap Mountain for R, play [Infernal Plunge](https://www.magiccardmarket.eu/Products/Singles/Innistrad/Infernal+Plunge) for R on Ornithopter for RRR (RRR)
>
>  Play [Myr Moonvessel](https://www.magiccardmarket.eu/Products/Singles/Darksteel/Myr+Moonvessel) for R, play [Infernal Plunge](https://www.magiccardmarket.eu/Products/Singles/Innistrad/Infernal+Plunge) for R on Myr Moonvessel for 1RRR (1RRRR)
>
>  Hold priority, play [Erratic Explosion](https://www.magiccardmarket.eu/Products/Singles/Onslaught/Erratic+Explosion) for 1RR targeting your opponent (RR)
>
>  Play [Reverberate](https://www.magiccardmarket.eu/Products/Singles/Magic+2012/Reverberate) for RR targeting Erratic Explosion, target your opponent again with the copy
>
>  Reveal [Dead Drop](https://www.magiccardmarket.eu/Products/Singles/Khans+of+Tarkir/Dead+Drop) (the only non-land in your deck) to Erratic Explosion, dealing 10 damage
>
>  Reveal [Dead Drop](https://www.magiccardmarket.eu/Products/Singles/Khans+of+Tarkir/Dead+Drop) again to the Erratic Explosion copy, dealing 10 damage

Comment: cool card that Burnt Offering, I wasn't familiar with it :)

Comment: It has a friend as well - Metamorphosis.

Comment: nice didn't know that one either. I do know their blue friend Energy Tap which is somewhat similar

Comment: To find all their friends, use an "Add Pool" rules text search in gatherer and restrict by CMC.  Always a good start for minimalist challenges!

Answer (score 2):

Well since you didn't specify "no randomness"...

**€0,16:**
Mountain (€0)
[Mana Clash](https://www.magiccardmarket.eu/Products/Singles/Eighth+Edition/Mana+Clash) (€0,16)
Your opponent flips tails, you flip heads, repeat twenty times, opponent takes twenty damage.

Comment: Nice one, but it's not in the spirit of the question I think so I added a "no randomness" rule to my question,

Answer (score 1):

Cards used:

- [Reverberate (Magic 2012)](https://www.magiccardmarket.eu/Products/Singles/Magic+2012/Reverberate) - €0,37
- 4 x [Rite of Flame (Coldsnap)](https://www.magiccardmarket.eu/Products/Singles/Coldsnap/Rite+of+Flame) - 4 x€0,75 = €3,00
- Mountain
- [Sorin's Vengeance (Magic 2012)](https://www.magiccardmarket.eu/Products/Singles/Magic+2012/Sorin%27s+Vengeance) - €0,54
- 2 x [Manamorphose (Shadowmoor)](https://www.magiccardmarket.eu/Products/Singles/Shadowmoor/Manamorphose) - 2 x €2,19 = €4,38

**Total €8,29**

How:

- Play mountain
- Cast 4 times Rite of Flame (RRRRRRRRRR in pool)
- Cast 2 times Manamorphose adding B. (BBBBRRRRRR in pool)
- Cast Sorin's Vengeance copying it with Reverberate